# Can installing older DirectX on Windows 11 mess up the system?

Tags: windows, windows-11, directx

Pretty dumb question overall so I apologise in advance. I want to play an older game on Windows 11 (Max Payne 1, RIP James McCaffrey). Since it's really old I used this mega pack that includes a ton of fixes for the game: https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1633394421

One of the options was "Option 6a, The install of this file insures all proper directX files are on the system, preventing possible faulty conditions. If already available it will be skipped automatically."

Basically it launched ms-dxwebsetup and I saw it downloading and installing DirectX9 and some other versions (older than 9).

Since I really can't see anything related to DirectX installed in Control Panel's Program and Features, can doing this potentially cause issues in the system? Reason I'm asking is because since this is a semi fresh install, everything is working perfectly and didn't want to cause any issues, not fond of the idea of installing multiple directX runtimes etc, hence my question.

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not mess up your system ***but there is no point to doing it***.
  On the other hand, the OTHER STUFF in that pack I make no guarantees about.

Microsoft has code in Windows to block old (Microsoft only) installers that aren't compatible with the system.

In addition to this, the dxsetup program also checks versions.

[This post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-11-and-directx90c-support/0da28157-1791-4d55-bb8f-6cdac90368a6) on Microsoft communities will point you to [the version](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ie/download/details.aspx?id=8109) I just installed in my Windows 11 VM.

If you run the installer, it will check the versions.. ask Microsoft if there is a newer one, and look very busy probably doing nothing.. it might add functionality but I seriously doubt it.  I checked the versions supported AFTER running the installer and it is the same as before.

The directX install appears to be pointless so why even risk it?
It appears that A vanilla Windows 11 already has support for DirectX 9.

1. Run "dxdiag.exe"
   [image]
2. Move to the "Display" tab and home in on the Drivers group.  Specifically, you will be looking at the "Feature Levels" line.
   [image]
3. Scroll down to the end of the line and you will see that you already have support for DX9.  This list looked the same before and after running the installer.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

NO.  You cannot overwrite Windows 11 DirectX with an older DirectX.  That will not work.

Can you mess up your Windows 11 system trying?   Most certainly. It depends on what the old version does.

Two solutions:

(1) With a fast enough machine and fast disk, try an older operating system (like Windows 7) in a virtual machine.

(2) Find a older computer to play the game. This may be the best solution for a game (intense graphics).

Comment: As stated, driver packages certainly can cause issues. In addition to accidental incompatibility, some third-party driver packs can contain malware. General rule: check any download at VirusTotal *before* using it -- that at least will eliminate most malicious software, though it won't guarantee that the software will work.

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to know if installing older directx versions could potentially cause any sort of conflicts. If each runtime versions are contained and only used when a game calls for it then I guess that should be ok. I'm just not fond of installing tons of dependencias and what not unless it's absolutely necessary

Comment: I have, however, answered the question you asked.

Comment: DirectX 9c and DirectX built-into Windows 11 is compatible with one another. DirectX 12 cannot be removed.